# Trying to build Jest is throwing "Caching was left unconfigured."

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

I have the following `.babelrc.js` in the root folder:

```
{
       "plugins": [
           "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
           "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
           "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
           "@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode",
           "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
       ],
       "cache": "true"
}
```

but when it tries to run `node ./packages/jest-cli/bin/jest.js` I see:

> Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins, presets, and .babelrc.js files can be configured
>       for various types of caching, using the first param of their handler functions:

What am I missing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use new `babel.config.js`

https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babelconfigjs.html

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    plugins: [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What `api.cache(true)` is it for? What does it do? The documentation is still incomplete :( Thanks

Comment: @NickGnd Based on the source of `packages/babel-core/src/config/caching.js`, `api.cache(true)` is the same as `cache.forever()` and `api.cache(false)` is the same as `cache.never()`