# Error: Catching was left unconfigured. It started flagging this error after i installed font-awesome in my react project

Tags: reactjs, frontend, babeljs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

My project was working all fine until installed some font-awesome babel plugins to my project, ever since it has been throwing this error. I've tried uninstalling everything i installed but its still showing each time i start my project.

Here's the error message

```
Line 0: Parsing error: Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins, presets, and .babelrc.js files can be configured for various types of caching, using the first param of their handler functions:

module.exports = function(api) {
  // The API exposes the following:

  // Cache the returned value forever and don't call this function again.
  api.cache(true);

  // Don't cache at all. Not recommended because it will be very slow.
  api.cache(false);

  // Cached based on the value of some function. If this function returns a value different from
  // a previously-encountered value, the plugins will re-evaluate.
  var env = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

  // If testing for a specific env, we recommend specifics to avoid instantiating a plugin for
  // any possible NODE_ENV value that might come up during plugin execution.
  var isProd = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");

  // .cache(fn) will perform a linear search though instances to find the matching plugin based
  // based on previous instantiated plugins. If you want to recreate the plugin and discard the
  // previous instance whenever something changes, you may use:
  var isProd = api.cache.invalidate(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");

  // Note, we also expose the following more-verbose versions of the above examples:
  api.cache.forever(); // api.cache(true)
  api.cache.never();   // api.cache(false)
  api.cache.using(fn); // api.cache(fn)

  // Return the value that will be cached.
  return { };
};
```

whenever i make changes and i try to check it on the browser, it always shows that error message.

I need help on resolving the issue,i have uninstalled the babel plugins and font awesome installed.

This is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "finders-market",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-use-cart": "^1.13.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typeit-react": "^2.4.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

this is how my project looks like
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inDPy.png)

Comment: Hi there! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CarlosSpohr I have just provided more info

Comment: Hi there, it's sounds like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939445/trying-to-build-jest-is-throwing-caching-was-left-unconfigured